# Reading json object with key starting with '#' character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My JSON structure is as follows

```
"{"Key":{"#text":"100150410150347261963/output/Five String.mp4"},"LastModified":{"#text":"2015-05-26T15:33:39.000Z"},"ETag":{"#text":"\"5e5fd36802186f81109a9adedcb802fe\""},"Size":{"#text":"18831126"},"StorageClass":{"#text":"STANDARD"}}"
```

This is my code

```
var data = JSON.parse("{"Key":{"#text":"100150410150347261963/output/Five String.mp4"},"LastModified":{"#text":"2015-05-26T15:33:39.000Z"},"ETag":{"#text":"\"5e5fd36802186f81109a9adedcb802fe\""},"Size":{"#text":"18831126"},"StorageClass":{"#text":"STANDARD"}}");
var key = data.Key;
```

Now I want to read the value `'100150410150347261963/output/Five String.mp4'` but the key to this value is `'#text'`, which starts with a `#` character. How can I read this?

```
var value = key.#text;
```

or

```
var value = key.'#text';
```

is not working. Is there any way to read this value?

PS: Please ignore the escaping of double quote '`"`' characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
var value = data.Key['#text'];
```

Comment: @SerhatMercan why did you edit this answer? It broke the logic. Also, still_learning, why did you approve it?